# How to read files from Dropbox on remote server using Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dropbox

I want to run automated scripts to read files from a Dropbox folder on our server. I started looking into the dropbox gems that are out there, and they all seem to require the user to authenticate a session by opening a browser. This obviously doesn't make sense for an automated task. Is there a way to do this without requiring a user to actually open the browser manually?

Comment: Why don't you make the file public and just wget the url and read the file contents? You can invoke wget from ruby by the way.

Comment: It's a company, so making it public isn't a possibility.

Comment: Have you looked at the dropbox-api gem? This works over OAuth and doesn't seem to require you to authenticate in a browser: https://github.com/futuresimple/dropbox-api

Comment: @MarcBaumbach This comment suggests otherwise: "# Here the user goes to Dropbox, authorizes the app and is redirected"

Comment: Ah I missed that, good catch. Carry on then. :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that they all require a web browser is that Dropbox uses OAuth v1. There is a way around this that may not be 100% in spirit with the Dropbox API T&C.

I would start by creating a Dropbox account that will be the user account you use from the scripts. Manually login as this user and go to the authorization URL for your app and approve it.

In your scripts you'll create an HTTP connection that uses that user id and password to login. You'll need to keep the information in the response that describes the user's session. Use the session information to create a second HTTP connection to the authorization URL. Since the app is already authorized, you'll just need to capture the session token from the redirect URL.

The definite downside to this is that the password for the user is in your script. :P

Comment: Won't those sessions expire though?

Comment: They certainly will. That's true for even traditional Dropbox web apps where you are operating on behalf of a 3rd party user (where you'd normally use the redirect/authorize flow so you never touch their password). You'd abstract this code into something that you can call each time the session expires. This is definitely a hack since the OAuth folks really don't consider the use case of automation. They're only concerned with allowing an app to act on behalf of an active user without knowledge of their password.

Comment: Hmm...thanks. I guess I have to think about whether it really makes sense to use Dropbox at all for our use case then.